# Changing field types so graduated symbols are available

Tags: qgis, symbology, fields-attributes

I can't seem to make graduated symbols work. When I try to click on my column it doesn't show any options. 
I think these is due to those columns being formatted as text and not number. Any ideas how can i work this out?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 7):

Use the field calculator to create a new integer/real column with the following code

`to_int(dens_bru)`

or

`to_real(dens_bru)`

Then graduated symbols should be available.

Comment: +1 but I would use 2 lines for the code snippet to show more clearly that those are options and not a mathematical operation ;)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of selecting the column to be used for graduating, click the `Expression button` beside it. In there, you can transform your field from text to integer using `to_int("FieldName")`

In comparisons to the other answers, this one doesn't require a new layer nor to add a new column.

[image]

Comment: That's a good idea although if the column contains numeric data, why not change it to the correct type? It might solve other issues in the future.

Comment: @GabrielC. Fixing the data is the way to go if there is no other system/user depending on the current setting and the data is never refreshed from an external source.

Comment: That's sensible. +1.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the **Refactor fields** tool to restructure your table. It will create a new layer so you can try it without fear of corrupting your existing data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have tried this option before. However, when I try to save the temporary refactored file layer somehow it creates a file with all string type layers. Which is the correct format to save it? Also, fields with data with decimals (eg. "5,54") are transformed into "0".

Comment: Verify that your decimal separator is correctly set, i.e. "." versus ",". That's one main reason why a decimal field would be imported as a string field or its values mangled.